# Post message to channel using Microsoft Graph API doesn't seem to work?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I can't seem to post a message to a channel. I've tried with both work and personal accounts.

The error I get is **Bad Request 400 - message: Resource not found for the segment 'channelName'**. Any suggestions?

API used - POST /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'Test Channel'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-10-22T12:37:47",
            "request-id": "fb333ec3-55a6-4e66-a89b-710d16f8aef4",
            "client-request-id": "5a76f2d7-b132-78aa-711d-9d84fc9a4085"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to get the the channel details with?
GET /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}

Comment: Hello, Are there any updates on this?